# Eloquent Laravel - как объяснить странности с whereIn?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Ситуация такая - если делать запрос таким образом

```
\Model\Ad::whereStatus(1)->whereIn("category_id", $this->data['categories']->map->only(['id']))->get();
```

то все достаточно быстро отрабатывается, но если вот так

```
\Model\Ad::whereStatus(1)->whereIn("category_id", $this->data['categories'])->get();
```

то запрос растягивается на 5-6 секунд.
Фактически, разницы в том, что в первом случае я уже готовые айдишки передаю, во втором случае коллекцию с этими айдишниками. Но ведь коллекция - это их ларавеловский тип данных, почему такая фигня-то?

Comment: Коллекции это не тип данных. Полагаю, у вас в коллекции лишнее что-то есть, а не только id

Comment: Это именно коллекции Eloquent, само собой там дохера лишнего, но они разве не распарсиваются по-нормальному? Просто есть ощущение, что сами коллекции как-то по-другому передавать надо, а не как я айдишники дергать.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором случае, при передаче коллекции в запрос, происходит преобразование в массив всего дерева элементов коллекции с попутным array_merge. И я сомневаюсь, что результаты запроса соответствуют результатам запроса первого случая, т.к. в список IN в запросе передается совершенно иной перечень значений.

Если вы ищете более короткую запись, то попробуйте использовать:

```
$this->data['categories']->pluck('id')
```